# Square integrability of combination of hypergeometric functions

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, mathematical-physics, hypergeometric-function

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0402184.pdf) the authors discuss the following function defined on the interval $\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

\begin{align}\Phi(x)&=B_1(\sin x)^{-\nu+1/2}(\cos x)^{\sigma+1/2}\left\{\dfrac{\Gamma(1+\sigma)\Gamma(\nu)}{\Gamma(\zeta^\omega_{\nu,\sigma})\Gamma(\zeta^{-\omega}_{\nu,\sigma})}{_2F_1}(\zeta^{\omega}_{-\nu,\sigma},\zeta^{-\omega}_{-\nu,\sigma},1-\nu;\sin^2x) \right. \\ &+  \left. \dfrac{\Gamma(1+\sigma)\Gamma(-\nu)}{\Gamma(\zeta^{\omega}_{-\nu,\sigma})\Gamma(\zeta^{-\omega}_{-\nu,\sigma})}(\sin x)^{2\nu} {_2 F_1}(\zeta^{\omega}_{\nu,\sigma},\zeta^{-\omega}_{\nu,\sigma},1+\nu,\sin^2x)\right\}\tag{154}\end{align}

Here $\sigma$ and $\nu$ are parameters with $\nu\neq 0$ and $\nu\notin \mathbb{N}$. Moreover the quantity $\zeta^{\omega}_{\nu,\sigma}$ is defined by the equation $$\zeta^{\omega}_{\nu,\sigma}=\dfrac{\nu+\sigma+1+\omega}{2}.$$

Now the authors claim that if $\nu \geq 1$ then $\Phi(x)$ is not square integrable unless $\omega$ is a real number so that $\Gamma(\zeta^\omega_{\nu,\sigma})$ or $\Gamma(\zeta^{-\omega}_{\nu,\sigma})$ diverges and the first term in (154) is set to zero.

On the other hand they claim that if $0< \nu < 1$ then $\Phi(x)$ is square integrable for all $\omega\in \mathbb{C}$.

Where these results come from? They mention this in the end of page (31) in a way that it seems these are easy things to see from inspection, but I confess I'm missing it. How to understand when this $\Phi(x)$ is square integrable and get the conclusions the authors found?

Comment: Just after $0<\nu<1$ there is a $\nu=0$ case, which seems a little simpler, is that one easier to work with to begin with? It doesn't seem obvious at a glance. Making sure the $1-\nu$ term in the bottom of the hypergeometric function stays positive will be important, and avoiding any possible divergences from negative integers in the gamma functions.

Comment: The $\sin$ argument of the hypergeometric is good, because if $|x|<1$ the basic hypergeometric series is likely to converge for 2F1..